# cordova-plugin-media fails to provide Media constructor

Tags: plugins, media

cordova-plugin-media 3.0.1 is installed, but Media constructor is not defined.
var media = new Media(src, mediaSuccess, [mediaError], [mediaStatus]);

produces "Uncaught reference error: Media is not defined"

I am testing on Android 6 phone.  Any ideas why this plugin does not provide Media constructor?

Comment: This post could use more context.  What's your IDE?  What *exact* version of Android are you on?  Can we see some screen grabs of items installed on the phone?  Etc...

Answer (score 0):

This bit me a couple of days ago. Use `window.Media()` instead.